# The British writer or British writer

Tags: word-usage, phrases, nouns, articles, pronouns

I know this sounds dumb but I have just come across this sentence:

> *The book was Jude the Obscure, a novel by the British writer Thomas Hardy.*

So the phrase "British writer" is preceded by the article "the". But I am wondering if it is acceptable to omit the article because I have seen a lot of people doing it. (a novel by British writer Thomas Hardy)

Comment: You will see either 'British writer' or 'the British writer'.

Comment: "**The British writer**" is marginally preferable as British writer is defined by "Thomas Hardy".

Comment: I'm sure similar things have been asked before, but searching for "the" isn't easy.

Comment: Omitting the article makes it more clinical-sounding; including the article makes it more congenial-sounding. Both variants are totally acceptable here.

Comment: You would probably never omit the "the" in a casual conversation.  But the "the" is routinely omitted in newscasts, speeches, articles/essays and the like.